# Troubles in if-else statement in Rcpp

Tags: c++, if-statement, rcpp

With the following simplified code I wish to simulate from the N(0,1) distribution and return a list with the simulated values as well as a vector which depends on the simulated normals (see the code below). The problem is that the if-else statement is not working at all! Please, could somebody help me understand where is the problem?

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

//[[Rcpp::export]]

List cond(arma::vec epsilon, IntegerVector Nsim) {
int iNsim = Nsim[0];
arma::vec ans(1);
arma::vec epsil(epsilon);
arma::vec vans  = arma::zeros(iNsim);
arma::vec vcond = arma::zeros(iNsim);
LogicalVector cond;
RNGScope scope;

for (int i=0; i<iNsim; i++) {

  ans = Rcpp::rnorm(1, 0.0, 1.0);
  vans.row(i) = ans[0];
  cond = abs(ans) >= epsil;
  if (cond) {
    vcond.row(i) = 10;
  } else {
    vcond.row(i) = -10;
  }
}

return List::create(
    _["sim"] = vans,
    _["cond"] = vcond);  
}
```

I run it in R by saving it to file.cpp and then by sourceCpp("file.cpp").

Comment: What a mess.  I tried to clean it up.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but `cond = abs(ans) >= epsil;` here, are you sure you aren't comparing memory addresses?

Comment: No not really! I'm a newbie in C/c++ and not so sure about that ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original code is confused about where to use a vector, and where to use a scalar.

He is shorter and repaired version:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

//[[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame cond(double epsil, int iNsim) {
  double ans;
  NumericVector vans(iNsim);
  NumericVector vcond(iNsim);
  RNGScope scope;

  for (int i=0; i<iNsim; i++) {
    ans = R::rnorm(0.0, 1.0);
    vans[i] = ans;
    if (fabs(ans) >= epsil) {
      vcond[i] = 10;
    } else {
      vcond[i] = -10;
    }
  }

  return DataFrame::create(_["sim"] = vans,
                           _["cond"] = vcond);  
}
```

Besides using (and passing) scalars where scalars were meant to be used, it also corrects `abs()` to `fabs()` -- a common C/C++ problem. I also reverted to Rcpp vectors - as much as I like to use Armadillo, it wasn't needed here.

Here is example output given a random seed:

```
 R> sourceCpp("/tmp/erlis.cpp")
 R> set.seed(1)
 R> cond(1.0, 6)   
         sim cond              
 1 -0.626454  -10
 2  0.183643  -10
 3 -0.835629  -10 
 4  1.595281   10
 5  0.329508  -10
 6 -0.820468  -10
 R>
```

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use std::abs() in C++. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/abs/  and  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I had been bitten by that before in the past, but it may have in the C context.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

//[[Rcpp::export]]

List cond(arma::vec epsilon, IntegerVector Nsim) {
int iNsim = Nsim[0];
arma::vec ans(1);
arma::vec epsil(epsilon);
arma::vec vans  = arma::zeros(iNsim);
arma::vec vcond = arma::zeros(iNsim);
LogicalVector cond;
RNGScope scope;

for (int i=0; i<iNsim; i++) {

  ans = Rcpp::rnorm(1, 0.0, 1.0);
  vans.row(i) = ans[0];
    bool go_ = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < ans.size(); i++)
        if(abs(ans[i]) < epsil[0])
            go_ = false;

  if (go_) {
    vcond.row(i) = 10;
  } else {
    vcond.row(i) = -10;
  }
}

return List::create(
    _["sim"] = vans,
    _["cond"] = vcond);  
}
```

Comment: > Rcpp::sourceCpp('Dropbox/R/C/fib.cpp')
fib.cpp: In function ‘Rcpp::List cond(arma::vec, Rcpp::IntegerVector)’:
fib.cpp:22: error: cannot convert ‘const arma::mtGlue<unsigned int, arma::eOp<arma::Col<double>, arma::eop_abs>, arma::Col<double>, arma::glue_rel_gteq>’ to ‘bool’ in initialization

Comment: I see. what you want to check in the if statement?

Comment: To my function I pass a constant epsilon as well as many other variables, and if some value computed by the function is less then epsilon I have many expressions to evaluate, else I evaluate other expressions. In my original code I have the if-else statement laying inside a while loop, but the core of the problem is the same.

Comment: Doesn't work ither! Is not possible to put that function inside the cond function, is not permitted. Also letting the function compar_x outside and the calling it inside cond doesn't work ither: it gives